# How to make a subdomain with password on a Ubuntu VPS

Tags: linux, .htaccess, ubuntu, apache2, subdomain

Hi i tried to make a subdomain with password for my website with VirtualHost. For some reason it did'nt work and i do not know why it does that.

What should i use? .htaccess or VirtualHost

This is what i tried in the virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    ServerAdmin example@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    # Admin email, Server Name (domain name) and any aliases
    ServerAdmin example@example.com
    ServerName  dev.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/dev/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Did i miss a step or did i do something entirely wrong?

Comment: What exactly didn't work? the subdomaining or the password protection? Giving more details would be helpful (e.g. your .htacccess file): is the password prompt showing at at all? Is it giving an internal server error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The virtualhost will enable you to create the subdomain and map it to a directory (as you have done).

For password protection via .htaccess, you need to provide the necessary configuration

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

[Source: http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/password-protection/](http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/password-protection/)

To create the .htpasswd file you can use `htpasswd`

```
htpasswd -c .htpassword testuser
```

Comment: For some reason i do not get the prompt to login when i go to the subdomain. Also i can access the dev subdomain at example.com/dev. Did i miss a step?

Comment: Try steps here: http://smartwebdeveloper.com/apache/htaccess-problems but most likely due to "Htaccess Disabled by AllowOverride Setting"